# I wonder what's better use of memory for LaTeX including many tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, memory

I am finishing a book with a bunch of complex TikZ embedded pictures, some with complex path decorations and so.  I wonder what is better, to include the whole list of `usetikzlibrary{}` at the top of the LaTeX doc or specify the needed ones inside each `tikzpicture`, yet repeating

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but worth knowing in this context: Use of memory, and the time it takes to process vector diagrams, is one reason why print-on-demand services may refuse to accept PDF with vector diagrams. Each copy is individually loaded to memory, and often printed only once. Since the printing is to paper, there is no advantage to scalable graphics. Raster images only.

Comment: Something I had never thought could be.  I suppose, printing on paper, normal paper, at low resolutions wouldn't make use of the high quality diagrams and graphics TikZ is able to.  But for on line viewing, zooming, on retina monitors, pdf is a must

Comment: Yes, that is true, but... Printer will usually accept raster images at sufficiently high resolution. As for online viewing, if the diagrams have a lot of white space (so that png compression reduces raster file size) it may be possible to create high-resolution png, which can be magnified by the user (within limits) in HTML instead of PDF. Advantage to HTML is no page breaks.